# What are the system requirements for working with heavy/complex scene in Blender?

Tags: rendering, animation, physics

Is it possible to create a scene like kung fu panda with more that 5 characters, environment, simulation, vfx, lighting ...etc.[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to give a cold hard and exact hardware estimate as a "requirement" for making this scene. Aside from having enough RAM (which isn't easily determined either, depends on many many factors), and being able to run blender at all, you could technically make this on pretty much any hardware. What hardware you *want* to work with is what matters, and that can only be answered by you..

Comment: This question if about peoples opinions and what they know . There is no exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, the minimum for rendering/composting this type of scene in less than 20 hours is and Nvidia GTX 650+ and either intel i5 or i7. But, your question was a bit vague so I don't really know what you mean. I hoped this answer helped though. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having (Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2690, 8 core)*2, ( 64 gb ram) (nvidia gtx 780 ti)*2, I am trying to re-create this scene as a sequence to check that how much can blender handle. I heard that blender can't handle heavy scene and it will crash.

Comment: There are no requirements. Even a Windows XP can create this, it will just take a long time to make. Probably another you might want is a good fan. The computer would burn out if you don't have one. I think this podcast might help. http://www.blenderguru.com/podcasts/ep53-harddrive-wonder-theres-lesson/

Comment: It can also depend on whether you are using GPU or CPU rendering.  With GPU rendering, you are limited to the amount of RAM in your video cards.  So if the entire scene cannot fit into the GPU's memory, then you will be limited to CPU rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a GPU that supports the Blender Cycles Engine. It saves you a lot of time. But be careful some GPUs aren't supported, that's why I had to buy a new one. But as @NuclearBoofluff said, this question is a bit to vast.

Comment: what about if let's say i have a laptop with an additional external VGA... would it possible? @Marten Zander...